# Does rectification of a stereo pair of images change the baseline?

Tags: image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

I have a sequence of rectified stereo images, with the left camera as the reference, (R0 is identity and T0 ~ 0). I have extrinsics on the right camera, R1 and T1, where the x component of T1 is the baseline.

I also have projection matrices before and after rectification, K0 and K1, and K0_rect and K1_rect.

If I am just using the rectified projection matrices, can I still use the baseline from T1, or has it changed?

Also, the rectified projection matrices is a 3x4 matrix, which is all zeroes except for the x component of K1_rect, which has a nonzero number.

Thanks!

Comment: I find image rectification very cool, can you share any pair of your own images that are nicely rectified ? For your question, it would be good to tell us what experience you have in this problem, so I wouldn't point you to the basics as http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/FUSIELLO/tutorial.html or http://www.sci.utah.edu/~gerig/CS6320-S2013/Materials/CS6320-CV-F2012-Rectification.pdf

Comment: I think the baseline after and before rectification is not going to change. Baseline is the length between the two cameras' center. And rectification did not change the center of cameras. And I've tried to print out the baseline before and after rectification their numbers look the same.(If I did everything right.) Just exchanging some thoughts! Please correct me if I was wrong!